# Java - codigo cesar falla en palabras

Tags: java

Estoy probando un código que cambia las letras según la distancia indicada (cifrado cesar)

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
public String code(String text, int distance){

        if (distance <0){           
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (char character : text.toCharArray()) {
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile ("^[a-zA-Z]*$");
            Matcher mat = pat.matcher(text);

            if (mat.matches()) {              
                character = Character.toLowerCase(character);   
                int originalAlphabetPosition = character - 'a';
                int newAlphabetPosition = (originalAlphabetPosition + distance) % 26;     
                char newCharacter = (char) ('a' + newAlphabetPosition);            
                result.append(newCharacter);
            } else {
                result.append(character);                           
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

El test que no pasa es este:

```
void testCode() {
    assertEquals("bgig.fuurumoiu", pac2Ex4.code("vaca.zoologico", 6));
}
```

El error mostrado es:

```
expected: <bgig.fuurumoiu> but was: <vaca.zoologico>
Expected :bgig.fuurumoiu
Actual   :vaca.zoologico
```

En cambio, los test que muestro a continuación, sí:

```
void testCode() {
    assertEquals("b", pac2Ex4.code("a", 1));
    assertEquals("d", pac2Ex4.code("a", 3));
    assertEquals("-", pac2Ex4.code("-", 3));
    assertEquals("z", pac2Ex4.code("x", 2));
    assertEquals("a", pac2Ex4.code("x", 3));

    assertEquals("b", pac2Ex4.code("a", 27));
    assertEquals("d", pac2Ex4.code("a", 29));
    assertEquals("x", pac2Ex4.code("x", 26));
    assertEquals("x", pac2Ex4.code("x", 0));

    assertNull( pac2Ex4.code("x", -1));
}
```

Al parecer, con un string de un único caracter funciona bien pero no para palabras.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?
No soy capaz de encontrar el problema.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es culpa de tu regex: `^[a-zA-Z]*$` paso a paso... el símbolo ^ indica INICIO DE LÍNEA, es decir, que empezará a mirar por el principio, luego vienen los corchetes con las letras, es decir, CUALQUIER LETRA, el asterísco, repite las veces que sea... y el $ -> FIN DE LÍNEA... le estás pidiendo que busque una palabra de inicio a final que contenga solo letras. El punto ***NO*** es una letra. Remueve el punto de tu texto, o añade un caracter de control para el mismo en tu regex!

Comment: exacto el cuantificador avaricioso es lo que te está jugando chueco porque hace que se verifique toda la cadena.

Comment: @RuslanLópez, me podrías decir a qué cuantificador te refieres por favor? Gracias

Comment: @Benito-B, I changed to ```^[a-zA-Z\\.]*$``` to consider the ```.``` , but it still doesn't work. Now changes  ```Expected :bgig.fuurumoiu``` and 
```Actual   :bgigNfuurumoiu```

Comment: @IñigoCatalánEchave me refiero al `*`

Comment: @RuslanLópez, ah! ```^[a-zA-Z\\.]$``` así decías. Gracias pero tampoco funciona. ```Expected :bgig.fuurumoiu``` y ```Actual   :vaca.zoologico```